# How to set a view to a tag set in code not in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that uses 4 different xibs, lets call them 1-4

So you start on view 1, if you press the button it takes you to view 2, on view 2, you have a back button (which takes you to 1) and forward button that takes you to 3 etc

Anyway, I am removing the next page buttons, and have added a swipe control instead of pressing a button, you can swipe to the next page.

However, I need to know how I can call a tagged view, using the swipe.

At the moment, the UIButton for next page is set in IB as tag 1

This is my swipe code (this is page 1 so only has a swipe left)

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        Page2ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2ViewController~ipad" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

    }else{

        Page2ViewController *UIViewController =
        [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:UIViewController animated:YES];

        Page2ViewController *VC = [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];

        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:[self.view.gestureRecognizers lastObject]];

        [VC release];
    }
}
```

Whereabout in that code, can I tell it to swipe to tag 1?

Would appreciate any help :)

Thanks,

Chris

---- Updated FAO Rob;

In the appdelegate.m

```
- (void)swicthView:(int)viewControllerIndex :(CGRect)viewRect {


        if (viewControllerIndex < 0 || viewControllerIndex > viewControllers.count) {
            //invalid index passed to function - do nothing
        }else{

            if (subViewForceUseNibSize == NO) {
                //pass the view frame size at runtime

                if (CGRectIsEmpty(viewRect) || viewControllerIndex == 0) {

                    //no frame size so force full screen
                    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
                        viewRect =CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                    }else{
                        viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
                    }
                }

            }else{
                //force use the nib size, so reduce size of NIB to leave display of NIB main nib below
                viewRect = ((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view.frame;
            }

        }



        //swicth our view
        if (viewControllerIndex == 0) {
            /*
             for (UIView *subview in window.rootViewController.view.subviews) {
             [window.rootViewController.view sendSubviewToBack:subview];
             }
             */

            for (int x = 1; x<[viewControllers count]; x++) {
                if (((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:x]).view.superview != nil) {
                    [window.rootViewController.view sendSubviewToBack:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:x]).view];
                }
            }

            [window bringSubviewToFront:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view];
            return;
        }

        if (((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view.superview != nil) {
            ((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view.frame = viewRect;
            [window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view];
            [window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view];
        }else{
            ((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view.frame = viewRect;
            [window.rootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).view];
            [window.rootViewController.view addSubview:((UIViewController *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllerIndex]).view];


        }

    }
```

Comment: shouldn't your left swipe method just pop the view controller to go back to view 1?

Comment: I don't understand why the `else` clause in your code is trying to create two view controllers with NibName `Page2ViewController`. You should do this just once, surely. And I don't understand why you don't `release` the poorly named `UIViewController` variable (it should be `viewController` or just `controller`, but it's not smart to name a variable the same as a class) ... surely you must leak.

Comment: @calvinBhai swipe left is putting your finger on the right side of the screen and swiping to the left, which is more of a logical "go forward" action than a "go back" option.

Comment: It does have a few unnecessary lines of code with regards to beginner errors I admit, but I am still learning the ropes.

Would any of you be so kind as to provide a more streamlined code than the above? Which could change the view to a tag?

Comment: And of course if I am being too cheeky asking, then just how I can assign the tag to the view using the code would do fine, then I can look to tweak it afterwards during debugging.

Comment: This focus on "tag" is curious and doesn't really make sense in this context. You use "tag" property to identify subviews of a view, not for identifying view controllers.

Comment: Other than the problems I point out above, does your code work or not? I assume you've successfully created the gesture recognizer itself.

Comment: Hi Rob, please check below I updated after your code - Yes the original code did work and changed views but your code is far nicer (and better!) so I appreciate that.
The reason for tag focus is outlined at bottom of this page in my latest update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the revised code sample, it is clear that there is a `UIAppDelegate` method called `swicthView` [sic] that is used for transitioning between five different view controllers, all of which are loaded simultaneously. Given this structure, it is advised that you have a property to keep track of which of the five pages is loaded, and based on the left or right swipe, invoke `swicthView` to transition to that controller. Thus:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentPage;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentPage = 0;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    [gesture release];

    gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    [gesture release];

    // the rest of the viewDidLoad
}

- (void)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if (self.currentPage < 4)
    {
        ++self.currentPage;
        [UIAppDelegate swicthView:self.currentPage :CGRectZero];
    }
}

- (void)handleRightSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if (self.currentPage > 0)
    {
        --self.currentPage;
        [UIAppDelegate swicthView:self.currentPage :CGRectZero];
    }
}
```

Frankly, I'd strong advise retiring the `swicthView` design and rather employing a [custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). If you watch [WWDC 2011 - Implementing a UIViewController containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102), you'll see a good introduction about the importance of keeping a view controller hierarchy synchronized with a view hierarchy, and see some practical demonstrations of custom containers.

---

The original answer, provided below, was based upon the original snippet of code that was performing `presentViewController`. It turns out that a very different solution was called for, outlined above, but I retain the original answer for historical purposes:

**Original answer:**

I assume you have the following sort of code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

And then you gesture handler could be:

```
- (void)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSString *nibName;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        nibName = @"Page2ViewController~ipad";
    else
        nibName = @"Page2ViewController";

    Page2ViewController *controller = [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];

    // if supporting iOS versions earlier than 5.0, then you should use:
    //
    //     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    // 
    // otherwise you should use presentViewController as done below.

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    [controller release];
}
```

Note, I'm don't remove the gesture (unless you really don't want the gesture there when you return back to this view, which is unlikely). Also note, I'm creating controller, presenting, and releasing.

I'm not understanding your repeated reference to `tag` properties in this context, as numeric `tag` values are used for identifying subviews of a view, not for identifying view controller or anything like that. So you say "UIButton for next page is set in IB as tag 1" and later you ask "Whereabout ... can I tell it to swipe to tag 1?" It doesn't make sense to "swipe to a button". You could, though, have the two handlers, the button's `IBAction` (which I'll call `onPressNextButton` ... I don't know what you called it) and the `handleLeftSwipe` call the same method, e.g.:

```
- (void)handleLeftSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [self goToNextViewController];
}

- (IBAction)onPressNextButton:(id)sender
{
    [self goToNextViewController];
}

- (void)goToNextViewController
{
    NSString *nibName;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        nibName = @"Page2ViewController~ipad";
    else
        nibName = @"Page2ViewController";

    Page2ViewController *controller = [[Page2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    [controller release];
}
```

---

References:

- [`presentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75), the preferred method for modal transitions.
- [`presentModalViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a), the now deprecated method that you use if you need backward compatibility for iOS versions prior to 5.0.
- [Naming basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH) in the *Coding Guidelines for Cocoa,* for advice in naming variables and methods. Note variables generally start with lowercase letters and classes generally start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Rob, firstly, thank you very much, to say that code you have made above is a streamlined/tidier version of my code, is an understatement! Very neat, very clear, much appreciated.

The best way to explain the tagged element, is my view controllers on page 2,3,4 are 3/4 height, leaving the bottom 1/4 exposed from page 1 - using the code above, takes me to xib 2, however it is not the correct xib 2, it is a full screen one.

When in Interface builder, if I link a button, to take me to page 2, I assign the tag of 1, then it takes me to the correct xib 2 (3/4 height)

Comment: So I wondered if there is any way in your code above to specify a tag attached to where it is calling the page 2 view.

Comment: You would implement this, not using `presentViewController`, but rather through a technique call "[custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)" where a controller is allowing another controller to present a certain portion of the screen. It's a slightly complicated topic and I'm not sure I'd advise it for a new developer, though.

Comment: @user1695971 Also see [Custom View Controller Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102) video at WWDC 2011.

Comment: Basically, If I have a UIButton - what I actually do, is set that button to the following;
- (IBAction)switchViewButtonPressed:(id)sender;

that action, is the same across all 4 Xibs, the only difference being,  I set the tag against the button depending on the page.

If I directly swipe - it is not calling the switchViewButtonPressed so the wrong xib is displayed (not so much wrong, just full height not 3/4 height which its supposed to)

So in otherwords, the button works - but I want to remove them and swipe only - not use buttons to change views

Comment: Code for that ;

- (IBAction)switchViewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    
    [UIAppDelegate swicthView:((UIControl*)sender).tag :CGRectZero];
}

Comment: @user1695971 Having said that, I'd still encourage you to investigate links I provided for proper custom container view controller.

Comment: Hi Rob, i've added what is in the App delegate file so you can see exactly what it refers to, I added it to the original question above - in code formatting.

Comment: Yes indeed, the tag to go to the next screen would be 1 however, on the next screen (page 2) I would have the previous page tag as 0 and the next (to go to page 3) tag as 2.

So it would be a problem if I specify the tag in there as there is no way to set it for 2 different tags on a page where you can go either way left or right.

Comment: @user1695971 You created a chat, and we should move the discussion there. Long discussions about a particular person's code does not belong in comments. Chat is the right forum: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23241/discussion-between-user1695971-and-rob I've put a few comments/questions there for your review.